# How to make a web maven project depend on another web maven in optimized way

Tags: java, maven, war

we have web java ee projects using maven

The projects shared common webpages and their code
i want the optimized way to be able to run every single project (Hr , Payroll ,..) and also the aggregated project ERP

the main problem is WAR dependencies 
if module projects can run ,all WARs will contain dependencies which will make ERP build time consuming process

we made temp solution using a variable in parent pom to make modules dependencies provided to make ERP build faster 
and switch it off to make modules run
[image]

Comment: Create multi-module project. In war projects try to have only beans for current view and view files (jsf/web.xml/etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i know, no team like to make war artifact (web project) dependent on other war artifact. if you want to share login functions, it 's better to integrate single-sign-on module. if you only want to share some logic in the webapp, it's advisable to fork it and make it as a standalone maven project.

Comment: our code base for project layout are common
so we need to make it as a separate project